# invalid instruction suffix for `mov' (movw %ax, %ebx)

Tags: assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

When I try to compile the following program:

```
.globl _start
.section    .text

_start:     movw        $-23, %ax
            movl        $-1,  %ebx   # -1 = $0xffffffff
            movw        %ax,  %ebx

            movl        $1, %eax
            movl        $0, %ebx
            int         $0x80
```

I get this error message:

```
demo.s: Assembler messages:
demo.s:7: Error: invalid instruction suffix for `mov'
```

So, the root of the proglem lies here:

```
movw        %ax,  %ebx
```

But the thing is that I don't think what I'm doing is totally wrong plus that's the example used in the book I'm currently reading: [Professional Assembly Language by Richard Blum (2005)](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0764579010.html)

Comment: `movw        %ax,  %ebx` makes no sense. It is "move the **16 bits** register AX into the **32 bits** register EBX". How would you do that? Zero extending (`movzwl %ax, %ebx`)? Sign extending (`movswl %ax, %ebx`)? Are you sure the author didn't intend `movw %ax, %bx`? I can't tell from the use in the source.

Comment: `movw %ax,  %ebx` - that's exactly the way it's presented in the book.

Comment: Judging by the Errata section for that book, I would be a bit cautious about the sources in it. Just make sure, that for each explained thing you can write your own source without book, which works in debugger exactly as expected (watch out for all registers, memory and flags changes). And basically there's only one canonical book for ASM developers. Instructions reference guide. Everything else is like helper wheels on bicycle, extremely helpful till you get over certain level, then it's burden. Next useful ASM books are either detailed architecture of target platform, or math theory books.

Comment: Slightly conforming with Ped7g I would like to point out that a "professional assembly coder" would rarely mistake 32 bits registers with 16 bits ones. This, and the errata, may indicates that the writer is not accustomed to assembly as they claim.

Comment: Umm...there are 5 errors listed on that page for a book that consists of 576 pages. Now, I don't know Richard Blum, and I haven't read this book, so I cannot personally attest to its quality. But that error rate is nowhere near high enough to raise an alarm about. Errors have a way of creeping in when you publish a book, no matter how many reviewers it goes through, and I don't think mistakenly typing an extra "e" is sufficient to cast doubt on the competence of the author. The comments here are quite surprising to me. There are a lot more errata for *Effective C++*, a widely celebrated text.

Comment: @Cody: problem for me is, that you can't write error-free assembler by hand. I'm doing that here in answers, so I have some good estimate how often I introduce some bug (usually just syntax one which would be easy to fix if I tried to compile it). And I have huge practice in it (wrote several ASM-only applications for ZX Spectrum on paper, because I didn't own the computer). If you write source for a ASM book, you should have compile and debug it. ASM is enough confusing as is, you shouldn't add further confusion by typos in your text. Of course some bugs may have been introduced by editor :/

Comment: And you can't exchange esp/ebp in mov, if you debug it. So the source was not tried, just written.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't write, what you want to do with that program.

First you put `-23` into `ax`, then `-1` into `ebx`, then you try to move `ax` into `ebx`, which is not valid on x86 processor, as `ax` is 16bit, and `ebx` is 32bit register. `mov` can't convert width of data during processing.

To make it work there are two basic options.

- if you want only lower 16b of `ebx` modified (by 16b from `ax`), you can do `mov %ax, %bx`, keeping upper 16b of `ebx` intact. (in your case the result will be `-23` in `ebx/bx/bl`).
- if you want to extend the 16b value into 32b value, you can do either:

  1. `movswl %ax, %ebx # sign-extended conversion (movsx in Intel syntax)`
  2. `movzwl %ax, %ebx # zero-extended conversion (movzx in Intel syntax)`

In 1. the `ebx` (and `bx` and `bl` as well) will contain `-23`.
In 2. the `ebx` will contain 0x0000FFE9, so `ebx` will be `65513`, `bx` and `bl` will be `-23` if treated as signed integer. Or `65513` for `bx` and `233` in `bl` when treated as unsigned integers.

About the book... are you sure? Read that carefully again, must be a typo, or you are overlooking some tiny detail.